# CORS Error - getting a $compile error and XMLHttpRequest cannot load error?

Tags: angularjs, compiler-errors, xmlhttprequest, url-routing, angular-directive

**Why can't my Angular directive be fetched even if I provided the correct url - getting a $compile error and XMLHttpRequest cannot load error?**

I started with an angular app and I can't include a directive as I keep getting 2 different errors.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load / Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

- I have researched a bit and there were suggestions to set up a server t avoid that which I don't understand. Why can't I just build the app only using angular/html without a backend if I don't really need it. What could cause that error?

> Error: $compile:upload

- That apparently happens when the URL of the template is spelled incorrectly- however, I provide the entire path from the root ( templateUrl:
  'js/navbar/navbar.html') or is that wrong?
  Thank you.

project1/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js">    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-materialize/0.2.1/angular-materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
   <script src="js/navbar/navbar.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <header></header>

    <navbar></navbar>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>

</html>
```

project1/js/app.js

```
'use strict';
var app=angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.materialize']);
```

project1/js/navbar/navbar.js

```
'use strict';

app.directive('navbar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'js/navbar/navbar.html'
    }
});
```

project1/js/navbar/navbar.html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
            Hello
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use server to run your angular app or you might get cross origin error. The server will helps you to resove your file paths.Then edit your directive to be

```
'use strict';
app.directive('navbar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'navbar.html'
    }
});
```

I did a little [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wJx4Sp95iTEqgBZOsXUW) so we are sure your code is free of error.

I am not sure about using the absolute path but if you are going to use it then you have to type something like: "C:projects/project1/js/navbar/navbar.js" 
you could use http-server it's easy to install and use.
I hope that answer your question

Comment: Okay thanks. I just added a nodes express server and it works now. Could you explain why an angular app wouldn't work unless I create a server? If I used jus simple html, It would work-whats the difference to angular?Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. nothing works and Im not getting the XMLHttpRequest error but still the $compile error which must be cause by the directive (if I remove the directive from my index.html file, the error ges away). I changed the templateUrl: 'navbar.html' to 'nabber.html' like you suggested.